# Magento 2 full page cache invalidates everything

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache

i do not know if this is a bug or by design. I have been searching and getting a lot of mixed signals.

running magento 2.2.5 with built in cache and redis. 
i dont know why, but when i change 1 letter in a product name.. All the page caching is invalidated?!

is this a bug or am i missing some logic?

Comment: Same problem - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267024/magento2-indexing-full-page-cache-problems Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

seems odd but changing the Zend_Cache mode to

CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_ANY_TAG 
from 
CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_TAG works like a charm.

foundin the file vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Observer/FlushCacheByTags.php

in method "execute"