# Magento2 - Indexing / Full page cache problems

Tags: magento2, product, cache, full-page-cache, indexer

We are having long-term problems with **indexer** and **cache settings**.

After reading great [guide](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1NdtNz_LBxk-JsCBy8AvekZAkSPWOE0WCzE14Y9ki-5Q) by [@johnhughes1984](https://twitter.com/johnhughes1984) about `caching` and `indexing` we thought that everything will be alright with settings adjustment. But it's just only less horrible :-)

> Problem: If I edit&save product A, then indexer "processed" changes in
>   backlog(1). FPC (not sure if its FPC but product page load in 3
>   seconds instead of regular 200ms) of every product is invalidated not
>   just for product A. This cause huge load issues on our production
>   Magento installation.

Our setup:

- 2 stores
- 25 k products
- Magento 2.2.5
- indexer:set-mode schedule

Any ideas?

Thank you